# Show me post to review of my prefered/favorite tags first

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

There's an optimization of the Close queue where the review tasks with more reviews are preferred over the others. I think that we should do something similar but for all queues and ordering by tags, when no explicit filter is given, which are favorites (and do best effort to not show me posts with my ignored/avoided tags).

I presume this may bring complexity to the review queues, but at very least would increment the bounce rate of new reviewers (the gross stops before even completing ~10 tasks (I remember that Shog9 posted some stats, *somewhere*, but could not be found)), which I presume is because the queues simply spews you whatever, others simply robo-review because their objective is bringing the number to 0, others simply give up.

I know that the filter is there (for some queues), but I feel that it should be smarter than that.